# Monitor Cpu & Ram Uasge Via Web

Tags: monitoring, cpu, ram

Does anyone know how to make or where to find a script that will monitor CPU and ram usage, so i will be able to use it at my admin panel on web? I'm running a Debian 7.8 Dedicated Server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linux-dash script . Please check below for how to install .

Url http://linuxdash.afaqtariq.com/#/system-status